# WordPress login is now working, it just refresh the page and nothing happens.

Tags: login

I have two websites on hosting (Hostgator), Recently I migrated one more website to the same hosting from Namecheap. Now the problem is that all of the three website's WordPress login is not working, After adding the login detail it just refreshes and nothing happens.

Here are the websites

- http://vivopizzakebab.it/wp-login.php
- http://thermo-control.co.uk/wp-login.php
- [http://shelbycountytnlinks.org/wp-admin](http://thermo-control.co.uk/wp-login.php)

Even it does not give any error message like your email or password is wrong.

Is there anyone who can help me. I think the problem occurred after the migration. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: You mean to change wordpress username or email in php myadmin? i tried its not working,

Comment: Actually, its not showing even the wrong email or password error

Comment: debug true in wp-config.php file and check error

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lqkxsa 
 http://prntscr.com/lqkxxs

Check these two screenshots i did debug as true

Comment: Didn't work. 

I think there is a small error that is causing the issue. Could you please give me your email id I will send you the cPanle details to check the issue. It'd be a great favor

Comment: Just sent you a message on Skype. please check

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lql9fp